# Change language in SiteOrigin Widgets

Tags: plugins, widgets, language

Hello I am trying to change the SiteOrigin widget to German, but I am not succeeding. The admin and user of the site I have already changed to German, but it does not change anything in the SiteOrigin widget.

Do any of you know how I can customize this?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to ask the SiteOrigin developers.  If the rest of the site is already German and the Site Origin plugin isn't, it's entirely possible that the developers haven't added a german translation.  :-(

Comment: @TonyDjukic Thank you! I will ask he SiteOrigin developers.